# Using Iterator with Java Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, iterator, listiterator

Using Selenium to gather text of all p elements within a specific div. I noticed while using **List**, Selenium scanned the whole DOM and stored empty text. So, I wanted to iterate through the DOM and only store values that are not equal to empty text via **java.util.Iterator**. Is this possible? Is there a more efficient way other than the **List** approach?

***Iterator Approach:***

```
public static boolean FeatureFunctionsCheck(String Feature){
try
{

    Iterator<WebElement> all = (Iterator<WebElement>) Driver.Instance.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text()," + Feature + ")]/ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/div[@class='navMenu']/p"));

    boolean check = false;
    while(all.hasNext() && check){

        WebElement temp = all.next();
        if(!temp.getText().equals(""))
        {

            Log.Info("Functions: " + temp.getText());
            all = (Iterator<WebElement>) Driver.Instance.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text()," + Feature + ")]/ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/div[@class='navMenu']/p"));

        }
        else 
            check = true;
    }

    return false;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.Error("Failed()" + e);
    return false;
}
}
```

***Iterator Approach throws exception...***

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.Iterator
```

***List Approach Works, However Not Sure If This Is Efficient***

```
public static boolean FeatureFunctionsCheck(String Feature){
try
{
    List<WebElement> AllModelFunctions = new ArrayList<WebElement>();


    Log.Info("[Test-235]: Selecting Feature");
    for(WebElement element: AllModelFunctions){
        if(!element.getText().equals(""))
        {   
            Log.Info("Functions: " + element.getText());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.Error("Failed()" + e);
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`findElement` returns *one* `WebElement`. What you probably meant to do is to search for *all* elements with given xpath, using `findElements`:

```
Driver.Instance.findElements(...
```

Also the syntax is over-complicated. You can just get the list and iterate through it:

```
List<WebElement> elements = Driver.Instance.findElements(...);
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    if(!element.getText().equals(""))
    {   
        Log.Info("Functions: " + element.getText());
    }
}
```

BTW I have to fully trust that `Driver.Instance` is an instance of the driver (typically in Java you don't have capitals for class instances, so I'm not sure if I understood it right). A more common syntax would be something like:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // or another browser
driver.findElements(...);
// ...
```

Comment: List<WebElement> is storing all the elements and then logging based on a conditional statement. However, I want to know if it is possible to conditionally store elements to the List<WebElement> to avoid storing empty strings.

Comment: So your actual question is how to modify `.../ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/div[@class='navMenu']/p` to select non-empty text?

Comment: I mean why not use `.../ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/div[@class='navMenu']/p[text() != '']` if all you want are elements with non-empty text?